# Any tool to change JSP web page look and feel uses JSP filters

Tags: jsp, web-applications

I am running my website in Apache and Tomcat server. I want to change (or maintain) same look and feel across all the web pages. However I dont want to change my existing JSP code.

Is there any tool/framework which can use to make same Looks And feel across all the web pages? I believe that tool should implemented using JSP filters and change the FONT, style of the server HTML response on the fly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a tool, but a language. Its name is [CSS](http://www.csstutorial.net/).

Create a CSS file, e.g. `style.css`, put it in the public webcontent (there where your JSPs also are) and declare its URL in the HTML head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

In the CSS file you can declare the style of the page, e.g. making the default font Arial:

```
* {
    font-family: arial;
}
```

.. giving all `<h1>` tags a different color:

```
h1 {
    color: pink;
}
```

.. giving all `<a class="foo">` tags a different background color:

```
a.foo {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

etc..

Comment: Thanks Balus! but I am already using CSS in my JSP pages. I want some available tool which can be used to override the existing look and feel without changing the existing JSP code. However I know this can be done via JSP filters. However I can change the CSS itself to change the look & feel but existing look and feel is not consistent across all the pages.

Comment: Then either we have both a different understanding of the meaning of "look and feel" or you are not strongly familiar enough with CSS (and semantic HTML). Try to go to the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) and click a random design on the right hand column. Note that it's exactly the same HTML code everytime.

Comment: Thanks Again! I am not expert in CSS but i know how it works. Can you please explain how can I solve the problem using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you solved it but I think I understand what you want. I have an existing project and I wanted to create another page/mash up from the resources (CSS and images) used to create the site, and would prefer to do this using a tool instead of hand coding. The closest I came was CSSedit in OSX, but currently using firebug and hand coding to see the results. Needless to say it's taking much longer than I want.